# Battery SOC simple model with Python Pandas

Tags: pandas, apply, battery

I am relatively new in data analysis using Python Pandas.

I am trying to define a function with several conditions and then use the apply() function to model the state of charge (SOC) of a battery storage system.

Since I need to access the previous SOC I am using shift(1) within my function.

I am really trying to make it simple, but I still do not know how to limit the battery SOC to 16 kWh and make my code run.

I have the following Pandas dataframe
[Dataframe: electricity profiles for a house with solar panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2alR.png)

I then created two additional columns "surplus" and "SOC" within my Pandas Dataframe.

1 stands for electricity production surplus and 0 means the electricity load is grater.

```
Electricity_profiles_df['surplus'] = Electricity_profiles_df['Electricity Surplus / Deficit [kWh]'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)

Electricity_profiles_df['SOC'] = np.NaN
```

I then defined my function as follows:

```
def state_of_charge(surplus, SOC, power):
if surplus == 1:
    if SOC.shift(1) < 16:
        SOC = power + SOC.shift(1)
    else:
        SOC = SOC.shift(1)
elif surplus == 0:
    if SOC.shift(1) > 3.2:
        SOC = SOC.shift(1) + power
    else:
        SOC = SOC.shift(1)
else:
    SOC = 3.2
return SOC
```

finally I am trying to use my newly defined function and the apply() function row wise:

```
Electricity_profiles_df['SOC'] = Electricity_profiles_df['surplus','SOC', 'Electricity Surplus / Deficit [kWh]'].apply(state_of_charge, axis=1)
```

The following error shows up:

[KeyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCrpk.png)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hey mate, how’d you go? I’m in a similar bind, curious if you ever manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on a Jupyter Notebook. Basically you work in numpy arrays, and only at the end you add the arrays to a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

%%time
#Parameters
SOC0 = 0
sim_time = 90
A_demand = 1
A_prod = 1.2
max_SOC = 16

#Signals generation

    #Initial empty arrays
t = np.arange(0,sim_time)
grid_demand =  np.zeros(sim_time)
battery = np.zeros(sim_time)
charge_array = np.zeros(sim_time)

    #External production and demand signals (can set any shape of curve)
prod = (np.sin(t/(2*np.pi))*A_prod + A_prod)/2
demand = np.ones(sim_time)*A_demand

#Estimates battery SOC
SOC = SOC0
for i in t:

   battery[i] = SOC

    #Energy required from the grid (No surplus)
    if demand[i] - prod[i] >= 0:
    
        #Battery has some charge left for next step
        if (demand[i] - prod[i] - SOC) < 0 :
            grid_demand[i] = 0
            charge = -(demand[i] - prod[i])
    
        #Battery fully discharges
        else:
            grid_demand[i] = demand[i] - prod[i] - SOC
            charge = -SOC

    #Surplus of energy demand
    elif demand[i] - prod[i] < 0:
    
        grid_demand[i] = 0
        charge = prod[i] - demand[i]

    SOC = min(SOC + charge,max_SOC)
    charge_array[i] = charge
    
#Creates data frame
data_dict = {"demand":demand,
            "prod":prod,
            "battery":battery,
            "grid_demand":grid_demand,
            "charge":charge_array}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

#Plots
df.plot()
```